# How to anchor sprites of different heights to the same Y position

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I have multiple sprites of different heights but I want them to all look like they're standing on the same floor (y position). For example to make my first sprite look like he's standing on the floor I have to position him at

```
CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX, y: 200)
```

But my other sprite who is slightly different size, to make him look like he's standing on the same floor I have to position him at

```
CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX, y: 150)
```

Is it possible to anchor different sized sprites to the same y position? Like anchor the bottom of the sprite to the floor so no matter how big or small the sprite, the bottom will always be at the same y value?

So for example no matter the height of the sprite, if I set a Y of 200 for example, their feet will always be at Y of 200 and their body will grow upwards from there

Comment: Would I be right in thinking that the sprite that you have to place at y: 200 is 400 points high? And the one placed at y: 150 is 300 points high?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using SKSpriteNodes, yes, there is an easy way to do this.

Each SKSpriteNode has a property called ["anchor point"](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skspritenode#2647041). In design terms, this is the origin, the point from which the object is rotated.

It's also the point in the parent (the scene, presumably) a sprite uses to determine where it's positioned when you're setting its position values.

This anchor point is expressed in terms of 0's and 1's, in a bottom left to top right coordinate system.

ie an anchor point of (0, 0) is the bottom left of any SKSpriteNode, whilst (1, 1) is the top right.

Most sprites default to an anchor point of (0.5, 0.5), which is the middle.

Your positioning is compensating for this middle anchor point by the amount of height in your objects, and that's how you're getting them to the same y position (at their base) in your scene.

You can either compensate for the height of the object when placing it mathematically (or manually, as you are), or set the anchor point to the bottom of your sprites. Both will achieve the same effect.

eg. Set an anchor point of (0.5, 0) and your sprite is anchored at the bottom middle. Do this to all your sprites, and you can give them the same y position value, and they'll all be resting on that "floor", regardless of their height.

Here's a thorough breakdown of this, and its implications and possibilities:

http://www.garethelms.org/2014/06/help-with-spritekit-position-and-anchorpoint/

Comment: Thanks! I actually did exactly that before you posted this but for some weird reason it still seems like they're not being anchored at the same Y position. I'm thinking it must be something else I'm doing wrong then. Do the sprites children all need the same anchor point or just the parent sprite node?

Comment: If the parent sprite node is anchored at (0.5, 0), how does that affect the children of that node? I want the children to be positioned at the center of the parent, but the parent to be anchored at the bottom middle.

Comment: Can you draw a diagram of your relationships?

Comment: @Brejuro it's ok if you can't draw a diagram, just make an effort with words to describe your object hierarchy... because these comments are the first I've heard of your parent object that's other than your scene.

Comment: In a nutshell, @Brejuro, yes, you need to set all the sprites to have their anchorPosition.y at 0.0, as this is the bottom... alignment point, for lack of a better term. Anchor is really the wrong word, alignment origin is a better way to think of it.

Comment: @Confused Anchor point is actually quite descriptive, because if you scale or rotate the sprite, the anchorPoint will not move - it'll be 'anchored' to it's current place, as though there was a pin going through that point into the scene and the sprite will scale from or rotate about the pin position.